# Connection to .mdf database on local machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, mdf

I'm creating a C# application with a SQL Server `.mdf` database file. I need to install it on the user's computer, however I'm having trouble connecting to the database, the computer does not have SQL Server.

The system will only be on a local computer.

What would be the best option to connect to my `.mdf` database file?

Connecting to the database:

```
public Banco()
{
    string Caminho = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + @"\AppData\Banco.mdf";

    string sStringConexao = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + Caminho + ";Integrated Security=True";

    _conexao = new SqlConnection(sStringConexao);
    _comando = new SqlCommand();
    _comando.Connection = _conexao;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server (the `.mdf` database file); then **you MUST** install some form of SQL Server on that machine. To use the `AttachDbFileName` setting in your connection string, this **must be** SQL Server **Express** (and no other edition)

Comment: @marc_s, a LocalDB instance can also temporarily attach `.mdf` files, I did it not 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Okay, but do I have to install sqlserver on the local machine to use .mdf? does not have any type dll or a lighter sql server that will serve only for this?

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server, you need to install SQL Server. That much should be obvious. If you want to use another RDBMS, like Sqlite or MySql, or anything else, nothing is stopping you, but you'll need to provide your database file in a format that they understand.

Comment: Yes this really is obvious, my question was whether I would actually have to download sqlserver or would have something lighter to make that connection

Comment: @Blindy: yes - ok - LocalDB really **is** SQL Server Express - just not installed as a service on the machine; it's official name is "SQL Server Express LocalDB" - so yes, that'll also work